# Custom name for column not resolving when another table is included and referenced

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

While selecting a column name with a different name like so

```
=> t = TeamMapping.select('team_id as team').last
=> t[:team]
> 2
```

works. But if I add another table as an included and referenced in query, suddenly this behaviour breaks.

```
=> t = TeamMapping.includes(:user).references(:user).select('team_id as team').last
=> t[:team]
> nil
```

Please note that `user` table has no column whatsoever with the name `team`. I was not able to find anything relevant by searching on google. I would appreciate it if someone can explain what is happening behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select("team_mappings.team_id AS team")
```

**or** use `joins` instead

```
TeamMapping.joins(:user).select('team_mappings.team_id AS team').last
```

Hope that helps!